# Inverter exibição de Xml em PHP

Tags: php, html, array, xml

Como faço para inverter a exibição de um xml em PHP?
Código:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('link.xml');
foreach($xml->VERSAO as $versao) { ?>
<tr>
   <td width="10%"><center> <?php echo $versao->VERTEXT ?> </center></td>
   <td width="90%"><?php echo $versao->RESUMO ?> </td>
</tr>    
<?php } ?>
```

Ele começa a exibir do primeiro item para o último, como faço para imprimir do último para o primeiro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz um `for` comum iniciando do ***maior valor*** para o ***inicio***:

Exemplo:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('link.xml');
for($i = (count($xml->VERSAO) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--) { ?>
<tr>
   <td width="10%"><center> <?php echo $xml->VERSAO[$i]->VERTEXT ?> </center></td>
   <td width="90%"><?php echo $xml->VERSAO[$i]->RESUMO ?> </td>
</tr>    
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.!